# d3 and geojson with multiple features and id

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, geojson

I'm having problems with multiple features on my json. I wanted to divide it by putting in multiple features so I can differentiate by id. But whenever I try to place in an id property on the features it would throw a json is null.

Here's is the geojson I made

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                                    
"features": [
{ "id": "1", type": "Feature", 
  "properties": 
     { "adm1_code": "PNG-1252", "OBJECTID_1": 999, "diss_me": 1252,
       "adm1_cod_1": "PNG-1252", "iso_3166_2": "PG-", "wikipedia": null, "iso_a2": "PG", 
       "adm0_sr": 3, "name": "Milne Bay", "name_alt": null, "name_local": null, 
       "type": "Province", "type_en": "Province", "code_local": null, 
       "code_hasc": "PG.MB", "note": null, "hasc_maybe": null, "region": null,
       "region_cod": null, "provnum_ne": 8, "gadm_level": 1, "check_me": 0,
       "scalerank": 6, "datarank": 8, "abbrev": null, "postal": "MB", 
       "area_sqkm": 0.000000, "sameascity": -99, "labelrank": 6, 
       "featurecla": "Admin-1 scale rank", "name_len": 9, "mapcolor9": 3, 
       "mapcolor13": 3, "fips": "PP03", "fips_alt": null, "woe_id": 2346583, 
       "woe_label": "Milne Bay, PG, Papua New Guinea", "woe_name": "Milne Bay", 
       "latitude": -11.581000, "longitude": 153.487000, "sov_a3": "PNG", 
       "adm0_a3": "PNG", "adm0_label": 2, "admin": "Papua New Guinea", 
       "geonunit": "Papua New Guinea", "gu_a3": "PNX", "gn_id": 2132895, 
       "gn_name": "Milne Bay Province", "gns_id": -2195635, 
       "gns_name": "Milne Bay Province", "gn_level": 1, "gn_region": null,
       "gn_a1_code": "PG.03", "region_sub": null, "sub_code": null, 
       "gns_level": 1, "gns_lang":
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n2YZ3/  (I used fiddle since text area is limited to 3k)

any advice on how to assign an id per shape is appreciated! thanks

EDIT:

Also, is this the best way to have multiple shapes that are selectable and would have a onclick event so it will zoom in on the spot selected?

Comment: You really need to look at this sample from d3 website, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590. This is a zoom-able u.s.a svg map. Please pay attention to its json definition for all states. I used it in my project to created a zoom-able world-map (SVG)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, you are missing a quotes before the the word type for id 1

before:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                                    
"features": [
{ "id": "1", type": "Feature",
```

after:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                                    
"features": [
{ "id": "1", "type": "Feature",
```